# Replace substring with exception

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to replace certain characters in file name of pdf files.
My code so far:

```
for file in files:
    file_ed = file
    replace = [",","-", "The "," "]
    for item in replace:
        file_ed = file_ed.replace(item,"")
```

In addition I would like to replace dots "." in the file names. If I would include "." in the replace list though, it will also replace the dot in ".pdf" which obviously is not what I want.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace at once with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) (regex substitution) excluding the `.pdf` ending from the replacement (via string indexing):

```
import re

fname = '-filename_,a,-.b.c d The., f.pdf'
new_fname = re.sub(r'(,|-|\.| |The)', '', fname[:-4]) + fname[-4:]
print(new_fname)
```

---

```
filename_abcdf.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution may be:

```
for file in files:
        index = file.rfind('.') # in case there are more than 3 characters long extensions
        file_ed, extension = file[:index], file[index:]
    
        replace = [",","-", "The "," ", "."]
        for item in replace:
            file_ed = file_ed.replace(item,"")
        file_ed += extension
        print(file_ed)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all files have extensions, you can count the dots, and replace all but the last:

```
dots = file_ed.count(".")
file_ed = file_ed.replace(".", "", dots-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) here.

Example:

import re

string = "Hello, World. This is a| \string and here is .pdf file."

print(re.sub(r'(?!.pdf)[,|.|\||]', '', string))

Output: `Hello World This is a string and here is .pdf file`

Here we exclude instances of ".pdf" from the match.

Comment: Above I am replacing commas, periods, pipes, and backslashes with a no space, except  ".pdf" in the string

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of identifying the file extension, I would reuse functionality already available in `os` or `pathlib.Path`.

With `os`,

```
import os
for file in files:
    file_stem,ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    replace = [",","-", "The "," ","."] # dot added
    for item in replace:
        file_stem = file_stem.replace(item,"")
    file_ed=f'{file_stem}{ext}'
```

or with `pathlib.Path`,

```
from pathlib import Path
for file in files:
    file_p = Path(file)
    file_stem=file_p.stem
    ext=file_p.suffix
    replace = [",","-", "The "," ","."] # dot added
    for item in replace:
        file_stem = file_stem.replace(item,"")
    file_ed=f'{file_stem}{ext}'
```